# Objective-C - NSSet containsObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsset

I have a NSMutableSet which contains NSDictionary objects.  I add the objects to the set and then later I test for membership.  This is driving me nuts as it is not behaving as I think it should.

```
NSMutableSet *aSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
..
..
// add NSDictionary objects to aSet

// Now test for membership

if ([aSet containsObject:aDictionary]) {
  NSLog(@"set contains  object");
}
else {
  NSLog(@"set does NOT contain object");
}

NSMutableSet *newSet = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:aSet];
if ([newSet containsObject:aDictionary]) {
  NSLog(@"newSet contains object");
}
else {
  NSLog(@"newSet does NOT contain object");
}
```

You would expect it to print the same message twice. But it doesn't. It fails the :contains test for aSet, but passes for newSet.

I just don't see why this is happening.  I have confirmed that the objects (NSDictionary) that I am adding to the set are the exact same objects I am using for :contains.

Ideas?

Comment: Can you show how `aDictionary` is created and added to `aSet`?

Comment: Whatever the issue is, it is in code that is not part of your snippet above. I tested the following snippet and it was working as expected. https://gist.github.com/chinmaygarde/34c315da14b4cc6e6097

Comment: The dictionary items are simply added to the set as: [aSet addObject:aDict]; I figured it must have something to do with the objects, but then why would it work when I "recreate" the set. The two sets, aSet and newSet should be identical. If I iterate through the elements of the set and compare using :isEqual, I find the object just fine, but :containsObject fails.  Another strange this is that if I modify the dictionary before checking, as in: aDictionary[@"foobar"] = @"whatever", the :containsObject test with aSet works!.

Comment: I think I solved it.  It turns out that when you add a NSDictionary object to a set, then change the contents of that dictionary object by adding additional key:value pairs, the :containsObject fails.  I think it performs a hash on the objects when they are added to the set to speed up tests for membership - discounting objects whose hash values are far off the one being searched.  My dictionary objects changed after I added them to set, and were not being found, even though they were the SAME object, just with more key:value pairs.

Comment: In general NSDictionary is not mutable, so adding key:value pairs to a dictionary will create a new dictionary, which is a new object, which won't have the same hash value. You can try using NSMutableDictionary instead.